# jQuery JSON to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am modifying a jQuery calendar and want to change this code:

```
function getEventData() {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  var month = new Date().getMonth();
  var day = new Date().getDate();

  return {
     events : [
        {
           "id":1,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
           "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
           "title":"Dev Meeting"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),
           "title":"Hair cut"
        },
        {
           "id":4,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),
           "title":"Team breakfast"
        },
        {
           "id":5,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15),
           "title":"Product showcase"
        },
        {
           "id":6,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day, 10),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day, 11),
           "title":"I'm read-only",
           readOnly : true
        },
        {
           "id":7,
           "start": new Date(year, month, day + 2, 17),
           "end": new Date(year, month, day + 3, 9),
           "title":"Multiday"
        }
     ]
  };
}
```

I want to pull the JSON data from a database in a PHP page. So I it would have to look something like:

```
   function getEventData() {

  $.getJSON('../ajax/calendar.php?type=get', function(data) {

        return data;
    });

     }
```

But I am getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined" which relates to the rendering of the data here:

```
_renderEvents: function(data, $weekDayColumns) {
      var self = this;
      var options = this.options;
      var eventsToRender;

      if (data.options) {
        var updateLayout = false;
        //update options
        $.each(data.options, function(key, value) {
            if (value !== options[key]) {
              options[key] = value;
              updateLayout = updateLayout || $.ui.weekCalendar.updateLayoutOptions[key];
            }
        });
```

The JSON returned:

```
 [{"id":"1","start":"Wed Jan 25 2012 11:30:00 GMT-0800 (PST)","end":"Wed Jan 25 2012 11:45:00 GMT-0800 (PST)","title":"test"}]
```

Did a test on the PHP page and the JSON is displaying as it should. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the JSON you're getting back from your server.

Comment: @Brad events: [{"id":"1","start":"Wed Jan 25 2012 11:30:00 GMT-0800 (PST)","end":"Wed Jan 25 2012 11:45:00 GMT-0800 (PST)","title":"test"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `data` in `_renderEvents: function(data, $weekDayColumns) {` is the data you retrieve with your `getEventData()` method and store it there then. This being the case, you need to wait until the `data` actually has content that is returned from the ajax.

The block of code `_renderEvents: function(data, $weekDayColumns) {` must not be executed before the ajax has finished. You could wrap it in a function and call it onDataDone(), and then in your getJSON callback call that function.

```
var data = '';

function getEventData() {
    $.getJSON('../ajax/calendar.php?type=get', function(result) {
       data = result;
       onDataDone();
    });
}

function onDataDone() {
    // code that wraps the _renderEvents: function(data, $weekDayColumns) {...
}

getEventData();
```

Comment: I am still getting an error, and when I do $.getJSON('../ajax/calendar.php?type=get', function(result) {
       data = result;
      alert(data);
    }); it alerts object Object so I dont think it is pulling the JSON correctly

Comment: Can you try alerting data.id or data.start, for example?

Comment: Where are you accessing the `data` variable in your code? If you access the variable anywhere before it has been filled after your ajax has executed, it will throw that error. How are you initializing your calender - are you waiting for `data` to be retrieved before that?

Comment: So you inspired me to put the code in the function that calls getEventData() and get rid of getEventData altogether. This works, thanks bro

Comment: Yea, that would amount to the same :) Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` runs asynchronously so the return doesn't execute until later. You could either run an ajax request synchronously, or add a callback that's called when the ajax request has completed.

Comment: like this: callback=? to the url then echo $_GET['callback'] in the PHP?